# Pages in a PDF file created from images have different size/resolution

Tags: pdf, images, resolution

I recently created a PDF file from a bunch of images (all of format gif except one of format jpe).  In an image viewer, all images are of the same size and resolution.  However, after I converted them into a single PDF, the page of the original jpe image appears smaller in size/resolution than all other pages.  How can I fix this problem?

#### Edit

The PDF file is created using imagemagick under linux.

Comment: What software are you using to create the PDF? If we don't know that, there is no way we can help.

Comment: Do you have a zip file with all images and pdf that was created? What command line parameters did you use in image magick to create the pdf?

Comment: @sunk818: No zip file.  All images were saved in a directory and the PDF file was simply produced using `convert * output.pdf` with no other options.

Comment: @reflectionalist Your problem is too specific. Unless you can give us files for us to analyze, it would be hard to say.

Comment: I have same problem.  I think it is specific enough.

Answer (score 2):

While the resolution of the image files being combined may be the same, the DPI might differ. Resaving the problematic images with the same resolution but also the same DPI corrected the issue when I combined them again.

I stumbled upon this 5 year old question when I encountered the same issue. I solved my problem and thought it would be nice to contribute so that the next person to find this thread has a solution.

Comment: So what's your solution?

Comment: Ensuring both resolution and DPI are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and create the document in MS Word and then save it as a PDF I have never run into problems that way.

Answer (score -1):

In my suggestions and thoughts in windows I use tools converters softwares to convert print files to PDF

Some converters have option of resolutions and size to convert to PDF and compression to you can try them

I open Gif and jpeg files in windows fax viewer or Photoshop or Corel and print it to

PDF creator
Adobe acrobat writer PDF
Jpeg to PDF

Or online sites to convert some are free to

[Jpg to pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ps2pdf.com/convert-jpg-to-pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjancXv0-HnAhWWfH0KHW8EBywQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0NhLrsPvnJSqHmA7YXVXAT)

[Images to pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://online2pdf.com/convert-jpg-to-pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjdjYnB1eHnAhUn63MBHXtgARkQFjALegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw36cVWkTcQvwSH6Hols5DG7&cshid=1582254677955)